# How disable entity updating based on one field?

Tags: java, hibernate, entity

Say that there is a entity like `Document` and it has `type` field. When `type` is `draft` is can be updated. But when `type` is `created` hibernate should not save document with any modified values. Is it possible with hibernate?

Answer (score 3):

You can make an immutable entity, with the [`@Immutable`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/Immutable.html) annotation, in that case, you are not able to modify the entity, then it's persisted.

Another solution, is to make an entity read-only via session, as it's shown in the [official documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/readonly.html#readonly-api-entity).

One more solution, is to provide an [`EntityListener`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/listeners.html) for your entity, like:

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(MakeReadOnly.class)
public class SomeEntity {
    // ...
}

public class MakeReadOnly {
    @PreUpdate
    void onPreUpdate(Object o) {
        //according to filed value throw new RuntimeException("...");
    }
}
```